# By issue #193, how vast is the safe zone?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Issue #193 of *The Walking Dead* shows various places in the safe zone that came to be after

> Rick's death, and the time jump after issue #192.

I'm curious about how vast exactly that zone is. Last we saw the gang, they were in the Commonwealth, which is in Ohio, so rather east of the continent. Eugene and Maggie talk about rallying train rails with the "Western Alliance", but I don't know how far west this alliance is located.

The issue doesn't provide info about what is east, north, and south of the (expanded) Commonwealth, though I guess Alexandria, the Hilltop, the Kingdom etc are included in it and it has an Atlantic sea front. Did they reach Mexico? Was Canada claimed back?

Has Kirkman or any other TWD official commented on that?